# Cloud computations framework

Tags: c++, hadoop, cloud, torque

Are there any framework/library or program solving the problem of creating cloud-like environment? Imagine we have m computing servers and n users.

Users somehow connect to manager, choose problems' parameters, click "compute" and manager decides which server is free, or create queue, send parameters to the server, and get results from the server and send them to the user.

I've found TORQUE, PBS, Ganglia, Nagios, but at first sight they just ran some tasks at some schedule and that's all, but they are not interactive. I could be wrong.

P.S. Do OpenStack, Apache CloudStack or OpenNebula do what I describe?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to answering this question is to explain the terms you are using and the tools mentioned.  Once you understand these, you will see that you need to define the computing problem that your cloud will solve when the parameters are entered and the "compute" button clicked.

OpenStack, Apache CloudStack, and OpenNebula provide a managers for IaaS.  In IaaS, the compute resources allocated correspond to hardware that you would find in a datacenter.  Thus, you can request virtual machines, storage volumes and network configurations.  See [Wikipedia on IaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service#Service_models)

These tools are CloudOS's, because they provide a management layer that brings cloud computing characteristics to a data center.  With cloud you get rapid elasticity, on-demand self-service, a measured service, resource pooling, and broad network access ([NIST Definition of Cloud Computing](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-145/SP800-145.pdf)).  Essentially, managers like Apache CloudStack take a data center (a pool of resources), and allow users to request resources (on-demand self-service).  Requests for new releases or to release resources are processed quickly (rapid elasticity), and users are only charged for resources in use (measured service).  Finally, users access the resources through the network (broad network access).

In contrast, the libraries TORQUE, PBS, Ganglia, Nagios are suited to managing allocated compute resources.  As system monitors Nagios and Ganglia provide feedback on usage.  Based on this, you might increase or decrease your IaaS resource allocation.  TORQUE and PBS allow jobs to be executed across a pool of VMs.  Therefore, these libraries address the problem of throughput, i.e. how to make sure you are maximising allocated resources.

Now let's turn to your problem.  You want to solve a 'problem' in a cloud-like environment.  This means you want the flexibility of a cloud that can assign resources on demand.  However, you haven't explained what the problem to solve will be.  Is the problem one of assigning VMs to a user, or to execute an arbitrary piece of python, or to execute a large distributed calculation suited so something like [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)?

Comment: I was recommended to use ZeroMQ, I've found  that this pattern is almost exactly what I want: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-71

Comment: Great, and do you get a sense of what a cloud-like environment looks like from the answer that I've provided?